# How would I create a caption beneath a responsive image

Tags: responsive-design

Here's our test.
http://www.photoeye.com/test1/test4.cfm

How can I create a caption just below the responsive image? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is a responsive image that scales for any screen size. Captions have to scale with the image and there in lies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about not using `<figcaption>`, but instead two vertical divisions? The first inner `<div>` contains the image, the second inner `<div>` contains the caption. Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="my_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>My caption</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a HTML5 structure would help you in doing this, do not forget to add [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in your head tag above...

**CSS:-**

```
.resp-adapt { position:relative; }
.resp-adapt img { width:100%; margin-bottom:-2px; }
.resp-adapt figcaption { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
.resp-adapt a { color:#fff; display:block; padding:10px; }
```

**HTML:-**

```
<figure class="resp-adapt">
  <img src="xyz.jpg" alt="Image">
  <figcaption> <a href="#">Caption Link</a> 1</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TBbNE/show/)

Comment: No sorry. This is what happens when I put this code into place. note that the caption doesn't appear below the responsive image, instead it's above it.  http://www.photoeye.com/test1/test4.cfm

Comment: Close, but it's still being cropped by the browser vertically. The image and title must always remain visible in the browser window. Nothing can be cropped horizontally or vertically.

Comment: nothing has been cropped here, to prove check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/TBbNE/1/

Comment: No, that's an overlay. It must appear below the image.

Comment: thats an style for showing the caption of a image, you can adjust via css yourself...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TBbNE/2/embedded/result/ produces an image that does not prevent the browser window from cropping the image vertically. It does seem to work within the confines of the jsfiddle interface until the image gets really small. However in the full screen example, one can easily crop the image with the browser window. Just take the lower left corner of the browser and play with resizing and you'll see what I mean. Thanks.